# Custom navigation bar image with iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to adapt my application for iphone 6.

Everything was working well before when settings a custom background image to my navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarbg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Since this image is made for iphone 4/5, the width is not adequate.

Do you know how I could set a correct image for iphone6?

I've tried to name my image navbarbg@3x.png or navabarbg-667h@3x.png but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea ?

Update :
I have added the image I use:

[image]

Comment: iPhone 6 doesn't use '@3x' graphics as the pixel density is the same as iPhone 5 and down. Only the iPhone 6 Plus will use '@3x' images. I suspect the problem is in the "stretching" of the image?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not exactly, the image is being repeated.

Comment: The best solution would be to employ a "stretchable" image. In that case, you'll be able to use a single image for all screen sizes. What does you nav bar image look like? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I have updated my post to add the image as you asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a resizable image and set IT as the `backgroundImage`. Based on the provided image, your left cap inset is `82.0f` points. You can adjust this as needed to accommodate for the text.

Also, don't forget that `@3x` images are only used on the iPhone 6 Plus, **NOT** the iPhone 6.

```
UIImage *backgroundImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image-name"];
UIImage *resizableBackground = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 82.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:resizableBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 5):

May this also help, its work fine (if your image shadow or different )you can use this one also but different image you have to set as per scale of device:

```
NSLog(@"width is :%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);

UIImage *navBarImage =nil;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==375.0f) {
    navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"header-topbg-iphone6@2x"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width==414.0f) {
    navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"header-topbg-iphone6plus@3x"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
else{
   navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"header-topbg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

}

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

you can see below image for iphone6+:
[image]
Thanks.